# Restoring a MongoDB collection from a text file of json documents

Tags: json, mongodb, text, text-files

I have been given a text file, containing thousands of json documents (not ideal I know).
I need to put said documents into a mongodb collection.

So far, I have saved the text file as JSON and tried to mongoimport, added commas between each document and attempted mongorestore with a bson equivalent - all to no success

Here is an example of what is in the text file:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("78ahgodjaodj90231"),
    "date" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00+0000),
    "comment" : "Hello"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("99151gdsgag5464ah"),
    "date" : ISODate("1970-01-02T00:00:00+0000),
    "comment" : "World"
}
```

and so on...

Using mongoimport I get this error message:

- `Failed: invalid JSON input. Position: 16. Character: O`

After saving as a BSON file, using mongorestore I also get this error:

- `Failed: db.collection: error restoring from file.bson: reading bson input: invalid BSONSize: 537534587 bytes`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have the following data in the file:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("78ahgodjaodj90231"),
    "date" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00+0000),
    "comment" : "Hello"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("99151gdsgag5464ah"),
    "date" : ISODate("1970-01-02T00:00:00+0000),
    "comment" : "World"
}
```

We need to refactor it to a code like below and save it with `.js` extension, say `insert_data.js`

```
db.collection.insertMany([
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("78ahgodjaodj90231"),
        "date" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00+0000),
        "comment" : "Hello"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("99151gdsgag5464ah"),
        "date" : ISODate("1970-01-02T00:00:00+0000),
        "comment" : "World"
    }
])
```

Finally run the following command:

```
mongo HOST:PORT/DB insert_data.js
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to import the documents successfully using Studio3T's import feature.

After renaming the text file to a JSON file, and letting Studio 3T validate the JSON before import, it worked perfectly.

Not the best solution, but it seemed to work for me.